# How can I ignore all the forward slashes and just match the page with Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

How do I match a page if it ends in `B08FP95RQD`?

For example, I need to match:

```
https://www.amazon.com/Shark-IZ363HT-Anti-Allergen-Lightweight-Self-Cleaning/dp/B08FP95RQD
```

I tried

```js
// @match     *B08FP95RQD
// @match     .*B08FP95RQD
// @match     *.*B08FP95RQD
```

but none of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `@include` header](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#meta:include), which supports regular expressions:

```
// @include      /^https:\/\/www.amazon.com/.*?B08FP95RQD$/
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I match a page if it ends in `B08FP95RQD`?

Note: `@match` is more robust and recommended over `@include`.

**http & https**

```
// @match     *://*/*B08FP95RQD
```

**https only**

```
// @match     https://*/*B08FP95RQD
```